# What is the best way to use Parallel.For in a recursive algorithm?

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I am building software to evaluate many possible solutions and am trying to introduce parallel processing to speed up the calculations.  My first attempt was to build a datatable with each row being a solution to evaluate but building the datatable takes quite some time and I am running into memory issues when the number of possible solutions goes into the millions.

The problem which warrants these solutions is structured as follows:
There is a range dates for x number of events which must be done in order. The solutions to evaluate could look as follows with each solution being a row, the events being the columns and the day number being the values.

Given 3 days (0 to 2) and three events:
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 2
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 2
2 2 2

My new plan was to use recursion and evaluate the solutions as I go rather than build a solution set to then evaluate.

---

```
for(int day = 0; day < maxdays; day++)
{
  List<int> mydays = new List<int>();
  mydays.Add(day);
  EvalEvent(0,day,mydays);
}

private void EvalEvent(int eventnum, 
int day, List<int> mydays)
{
   Parallel.For(day,maxdays, day2 =>  
   // events must be on same day or after previous events
   {
     List<int> mydays2 = new List<int>();
     for(int a = 0; a <mydays.Count;a++)
     {
        mydays2.Add(mydays[a]);
     }
     mydays2.Add(day2);
     if(eventnum< eventcount - 1) // proceed to next event
     {
      EvalEvent(eventnum+1, day2,mydays2);
     }
     else
     {
       EvalSolution(mydays2);
     }
   });
}
```

---

My question is if this is actually an efficient use of parallel processing or will too many threads be spawned and slow it down? Should the parallel loop only be done on the last or maybe last few values of eventnum or is there a better way to approach the problem?

### Requested old code pretty much is as follows:

```
private int daterange;
private int events;
private void ScheduleIt()
{
  daterange = 10;
  events = 6;
  CreateSolutions();
  int best = GetBest();
}
private DataTable Options();
private bool CreateSolutions()
{
   Options= new DataTable();
   Options.Columns.Add();
    
for (int day1=0;day1<=daterange ;day1++)
{
    Options.Rows.Add(day1);
}
        
for (int event =1; event<events; event++)
{
    Options.Columns.Add();
    
    foreach(DataRow dr in Options.Rows)
    {dr[Options.Columns.Count-1] = dr[Options.Columns.Count-2] ;}
    int rows = Options.Rows.Count;
    for (int day1=1;day1<=daterange ;day1++)
    {
        
        for(int i = 0; i <rows; i++)
        {
            if(day1 > Convert.ToInt32(Options.Rows[i][Options.Columns.Count-2]))
            {
                try{
                Options.Rows.Add();
                for (int col=0;col<Options.Columns.Count-1;col++)
                    {
                        
                        Options.Rows[Options.Rows.Count-1][col] =Options.Rows[i][col];
                        
                    }
                Options.Rows[Options.Rows.Count-1][Options.Columns.Count-1] = day1;
                
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                 return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return true;
}

private intGetBest()
{
    int bestopt = 0;
    double bestscore =999999999;

    Parallel.For(  0,  Options.Rows.Count,opt => 
    {

        double score = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <Options.Columns.Count;i++)
        {score += Options.Rows[opt][i]}// just a stand in calc for a score
        if (score < bestscore)
        {bestscore = score;
            bestopt = opt;
        }

    });
    return bestopt;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a non-parallel version of your code?

Comment: Your code as is has bugs. You cant mulithread calls to Add. I am guessing you ment to do `List<int> mydays2 = new List<int>(mydays);` so each thread gets its own copy of the list.

Comment: You can control the maximum thread count by providing an argument of type ParallelOptions.

Comment: What does `EvalSolution` do?

Comment: You really need a [mcve].

Comment: Are you expecting `List<int> mydays2 = mydays;` to make `mydays2` as a distinct copy of `mydays`? or are you expecting `mydays2` to be the same list as `mydays` meaning that it doesn't matter which you add to both will get the same values?

Comment: My apologies, the computer I code on does not have internet due to security and I missed some things transfering. I will fix this up and provide my alternate code in the morning.  EvalSolution in the actual program looks at an existing schedule and uses some formulas to evaluate what combination of days will be optimal.  For now we could just say it adds existing hours scheduled plus the hours from the events.  The solution with the lowest evaluated score would be chosen.

Comment: Yes mydays2 was meant to be a distinct copy which would have the new day value added to the end

Answer (score 1):

Even if done without errors it can not significantly speed up your solution.

It looks like each level of recursion tries to start multiple (let say up to "k") next level calls for let's "n" level. This essentially mean code is O(k ^ n) which grows very fast. Non-algorithmic speedup of such O(k^n) solution is essentially useless (unless both k and n are very small). In particular, running code in parallel will only give you constant factor of speed up (roughly number of threads supported by your CPUs) which really does not change complexity at all.

Indeed creation of exponentially large number of requests for new threads will likely cause more problems by itself for just managing threads.

In addition to not significantly improving performance parallel code is harder to write as it needs proper synchronization or cleaver data partitioning - neither seem to be present in your case.

Comment: Thank you! The max values I expect to use would be around 20 events over 30 days, likely not both that high together.  Like you mentioned, I'm estimating the number of iterations to be ((events)^days)/2. My plan was to ensure the days allotted would not exceed some number of iterations such that the total processing time wouldnt exceed say 5 minutes. If I could speed up processing by say 4x it would greatly help. The users have been typically at around 8 days and 8 events processing in about 2 mins without parallelizing.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelization works best when the workload is bulky and balanced. Ideally you would like your work splited to as many independent partitions as the logical processors of your machine, ensuring that all partitions have approximately the same size. This way all available processors will work with the maximum efficiency for approximately the same duration, and you'll get the results after the shortest time possible.

Of course you should start with a working and bug-free serial implementation, and then think about ways to partition your work. The easiest way is usually not optimal. For example an easy path is to convert your work to a LINQ query, and then parallelize it with [`AsParallel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) (making it PLINQ). This usually results to a too granular partitioning, that introduces too much overhead. If you can't find ways to improve it you then can go the way of `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`, which is a bit more complex.

A LINQ implementation should probably start by creating an iterator that produces all your units of work (Events or Solutions, it's not very clear to me).

```
public static IEnumerable<Solution> GetAllSolutions()
{
    for (int day = 0; day < 3; day++)
    {
        for (int ev = 0; ev < 3; ev++)
        {
            yield return new Solution(); // ???
        }
    }
}
```

It will certainly be helpful if you have created concrete classes to represent the entities you are dealing with.